# Слитное или раздельное написание "от(_)руки"

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать слово "от руки"?

Answer (score 2):

"От руки" пишется раздельно. Такого рода наречий, образованных от существительного с предлогом, достаточно много.

***http://www.classes.ru/grammar/127.Rosental-pravopisanie/35.htm#з_06:***
Пишутся раздельно употребленные в наречном значении сочетания имен существительных с предлогами:
без, например: без ведома, без запроса, без обиняков, без оглядки, без отказа, без просвета, без просыпу, без разбору, без спросу, без толку, без удержу, без умолку, без устали;
в, например: в дым, в лоск, в стельку (пьяный), в подбор, в придачу, в складчину, в старину, в стык, в тупик, в тупике;
до, например: до зарезу, до отвала, до отказа, до смерти, до упаду;
за, например: за полночь;
на, например: на бегу, на весу, на виду, на лету, на скаку, на ходу; на вес, на вид, на вкус, на глаз, на глазок, на грех, на диво, на зависть, на ощупь, на редкость, на славу, на смех;
***от, например: от силы*** (три килограмма и т.п.);
по, например: по старинке;
под, например: под стать, под уклон, под хмельком, под шумок;
с, например: с ведома, с кондачка, с маху, с наскока, с панталыку (сбиться), с разбегу, с разгона, с размаху, с ходу.
То же при предлогах в и на с существительными во множественном числе, например: в головах, в ногах, на днях, на радостях, на рысях, на сносях, на часах (стоять).
Пишутся раздельно выступающие в функции наречий сочетания предлога на с неизменяемыми частями речи (частицами, междометиями): на авось, на нет (свести на нет), на ура, на фуфу; ср. также: на арапа, на шарап и др.

Answer (score 1):

Запомните такую подсказку: обычно пишутся раздельно употребленные в роли наречия сочетания имен существительных с различными предлогами, **если существительное в определенном значении сохранило хотя бы некоторые падежные формы**. Существительное **рука** существеут в языке во всех формах!